# Selenium WebDriver get text from CSS property "content" on a ::before pseudo element

Tags: css, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to verify the text "The information provided is either invalid or incomplete." is displayed using Selenium/WebDriver in Java.

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="validationError">
    <ul>
        <li>Required: Server Name</li>
        <li>Required: Receiving Port</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

with the following CSS code:

```
#validationError:before {
    content: 'The information provided is either invalid or incomplete.';
}
```

Here's my current java code:

```
WebElement errorBox = browser.findElement(By.id("validationError"));
Assert.assertNotNull("Could not find validation errors", errorBox);

System.out.println("Error Explanation: " + error.getCssValue("content") + "\n");

List<WebElement> errorList = errorBox.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
for (WebElement error : errorList) {
    System.out.println("Error: " + error.getText());
}

System.out.println("\nError Full Text: " + errorBox.getText());
```

This is my output of the above code:

```
Error Explanation:

Error: Required: Server Name
Error: Required: Receiving Port

Error Full Text: Required: Server Name
Required: Receiving Port
```

I can't seem to find a way to verify the text "The information provided is either invalid or incomplete." is displayed. Calling `getText()` on the web element also does not return the expected string, but will display any other normal text within that div. Any ideas?

Comment: can you provide the `html`?

Comment: Sorry, I had issues with the code formatting, I didn't realize you need a newline before each code snippet. Does it make sense now?

Comment: It does . However, do you know `webdriver` finds the element first or not? plus provide the stacktrace with the question for future reference please

Comment: Can you provide more of the HTML, including the text you're trying to access?

Comment: I have updated my HTML and included more java code to help explain what's going on. The page renders like so:

`The information provided is either invalid or incomplete.`
`Required: Server Name`
`Required: Receiving Port`

I'm trying to verify the first line, the "The information provided is either invalid or incomplete.". However it seems that since it comes from CSS I can't access it through normal means.

Comment: Oh, I see, it's a pseudo element.  I am not sure Selenium can select those.  I'll look into it more in a bit.

Comment: Might be a duplicate. The answer there is more thorough even though chronologically later: [Getting the values of all the CSS properties of a selected element in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32537339/getting-the-values-of-all-the-css-properties-of-a-selected-element-in-selenium)

Answer (score 29):

I am not 100% sure if WebDriver can retrieve pseudo element content for you. I think you would need to use Javascript. Below works, I tested.

```
String script = "return window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('#validationError'),':before').getPropertyValue('content')";
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
String content = (String) js.executeScript(script);
System.out.println(content);
```

This should print

```
The information provided is either invalid or incomplete.
```

Comment: No, it can not, I mean It is impossible to get access by selenium to HTML pseudo-elements.

Answer (score 1):

Tried the same, works for me.

Created sample html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
 p::after { 
  content: " - Remember this";
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p id='b'>My name is Donald</p>
<p>I live in Ducksburg</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Reused  Nilesh's code

```
    String script  = "return window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('p#b'), ':after').getPropertyValue('content')";
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) UIKeyWords.getUIDriver();
    String contentValue = (String) js.executeScript(script);
    System.out.println(contentValue);
```