# WebDriver select element that has ::before

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I have 2 elements that have the same attributes but shown one at a time on the page (When one is shown, the other disappears).The only difference between the two is that the element which is displayed will have the '::before' selector. Is it possible to use an xpath or css selector to retrieve the element based on its id and whether or not it has ::before

[image]

Comment: The elements dont have an id. Why dont you just select it using classname?

Comment: because both elements have the same classname

Comment: How are you differentiating between them in CSS, in order to apply the `:before` pseudo element to the correct one?

Comment: See this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/28265738/4720017

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium WebDriver get text from CSS property "content" on a ::before pseudo element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28244911/selenium-webdriver-get-text-from-css-property-content-on-a-before-pseudo-ele)

Comment: I think it would make more sense to filter them based on which is visible or clickable, if such a method exists in Selenium-webdriver. It exists in WDIO which is (javascript) webdriver-related.

Answer (score 4):

I bet also to try with the javascript solution above.

Since ::after & ::before are a pseudo element which allows you to insert content onto a page from CSS (without it needing to be in the HTML). While the end result is not actually in the DOM, it appears on the page as if it is - you see it but can't really locate it with xpath for example (https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/).

I can also suggest if possible to have different IDs or if they in different place in the DOM make more complex xpath using above/below elements and see if it is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

```
String script = "return window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.analyzer_search_inner.tooltipstered'),':after').getPropertyValue('content')";
                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
                        String content = (String) js.executeScript(script);
                        System.out.println(content);
```