# Testing contents of after CSS selector in protractor

Tags: css, selenium, css-selectors, protractor, pseudo-element

In my HTML I have element such as below

HTML:

```
<hmtl>
    <head>
        <style>
            label::after {
            content: " *"
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <label> I'm mandatory</label>
    </body>
</hmtl>
```

So what gets displayed on browser is:

```
I'm mandatory *
```

Query Selector

```
>getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('label')).content
<"normal"
```

So I see **`normal`** instead of **`*`**.

I can't see where is **`normal`** coming from. Is this the correct way to test content of `::after` CSS selector?

I want to test that there's a "*" after the label, but can't seem to be able to get the value of "content" property correctly. Once I'm able to find it in using browser DOM API, I'd eventually want to test it in protractor.

### Update

I found the answer at - [Selenium WebDriver get text from CSS property "content" on a ::before pseudo element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28244911/selenium-webdriver-get-text-from-css-property-content-on-a-before-pseudo-ele/28265738#28265738).
Now the question remains how I would test this on protractor.

Comment: from where word `normal`? Could it be that you get wrong element?

Comment: I've added a small HTML snippet and also the result of querySelector(). The label element is being correctly selected, but I guess there's some work remaining to get the proper value for ::after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my question was specifically w.r.t protractor I'm posting the solution that I got working. Coming to the part I was stuck initially - why do I get "normal" instead of " *"

```
>getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('label')).content
<"normal"
```

So earlier I was unaware that [::after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) creates a pseudo child element inside the label element.

Inspecting `<label>` element in Chrome shows the below HTML

```
<label>
    I'm mandatory
    ::after
</label>
```

If I click`<label>` element and checked the Computed tab, I could see that the value for `content` property is `normal`.

However, if I click on `::after` pseudo-element, I can see in the Computed tab the value for `content` property is `" *"`.

As mentioned in the other answers `getComputedStyle()` with the pseudo element as second parameter, is the only way to get value of CSS property for "`::after`". The crux of the problem is that protractor does not have an equivalent for `getComputedStyle()`, so we have to rely upon `browser.executeScript()` as shown below:

```
let labelHeader = 'I'm mandatory *';
// Passing label element separately as in the real test case, it would be extracted from parent
// enclosing element and need to be able to pass it as a parameter to browser.executeScript().

let label = element(by.css('label'));
browser.executeScript("return window.getComputedStyle(arguments[0], ':after').content",
                       label)
    .then ((suffixData: string) => {
     // suffixData comes out to be '" *"', double quotes as part of the string.
     // So get rid of the first and last double quote character

         suffixData = suffixData.slice(1, suffixData.length - 1);
         labelText += suffixData;
         expect(labelText).toBe(labelHeader);
     });
```

Answer (score 2):

### Window.getComputedStyle()

The [Window.getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) method returns an object containing the values of all CSS properties of an element, after applying active stylesheets and resolving any basic computation those values may contain. Individual CSS property values are accessed through APIs provided by the object, or by indexing with CSS property names.

- Syntax:

  ```
  var style = window.getComputedStyle(element [, pseudoElt]);

  element
      The Element for which to get the computed style.
  pseudoElt (Optional)
      A string specifying the pseudo-element to match. Omitted (or null) for real elements.

  The returned style is a live CSSStyleDeclaration object, which updates automatically when the element's styles are changed.
  ```
- You can find a related discussion in [WebDriver select element that has ::before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29772457/webdriver-select-element-that-has-before/53064275#53064275)

---

### Usage with pseudo-elements

`getComputedStyle()` can pull style info from pseudo-elements (such as `::after`, `::before`, `::marker`, `::line-marker`.

As per the HTML, the `<style>` is as follows:

```
<style>
    label::after {
    content: " *"
    }
</style>
```

Implemented as:

```
<label> I'm mandatory</label>
```

To retrieve you need to:

```
var label = document.querySelector('label'); 
var result = getComputedStyle(label, ':after').content;

console.log('the generated content is: ', result); // returns ' *'
```

---

### Reference

- [CSS Pseudo-Elements Module Level 4](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-pseudo-4/)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const label = document.querySelector('label'); // "normal";

console.log(label);


const labelAfter = getComputedStyle(label, ':after').content;

console.log(labelAfter == "normal");
```

```css
label::after {
  content: " *"
}
```

```html
<label> I'm mandatory</label>
```