# Extracting content in :after using XPath

Tags: css, xpath, selenium-webdriver, pseudo-element

I am trying to get the value of a CSS attribute "content" with:

```
WebElement plusOrMinusSign = currentEntityTypeLevel1.findElement(
    By.xpath("i[@class='tree-branch-head']::after"));
System.out.println(plusOrMinusSign.getCssValue("content"));
```

However, I get an error: `The string 'i[@class='tree-branch-head']::after' is not a valid XPath expression.`

It seem the "`::after`" is not recognised.

Html:

```
<i class="tree-branch-head" ng-class="iBranchClass()" ng-click="selectNodeHead(node)">::after
</i>
```

Css:

```
i:after {
    content: "-";
}
```

Any idea how to get the value of "content"?

Comment: See this post https://davidwalsh.name/pseudo-element

Comment: Try `//i[@class='tree-branch-head']::after`

Comment: @Nikhil, I am not familiar with using javascript inside a selenium project. Could you give me a pointer/example?

Comment: @ Girish, the "//" made no difference...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium WebDriver get text from CSS property "content" on a ::before pseudo element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28244911/selenium-webdriver-get-text-from-css-property-content-on-a-before-pseudo-ele)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are using `By.xpath` but `i[@class='tree-branch-head']::after` is not a valid XPath, it is a mixture of XPath notation (`i[@class='tree-branch-head']`) and CSS (`:after`).

You should use `By.cssSelector` and a valid CSS selector, for example `i.tree-branch-head:after`. This would work if Selenium accepted pseudo elements, which it does not.

To work around this problem, you can either use Chromium, that generates extra fake elements `::after` and `::before`, or use a Javascript extractor as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/28265738/449288.

Comment: Thanks Gieole, your `i.tree-branch-head:after` helped me on the right track. This is the string value for retreiving the value of 'content'.     `String script = "return window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('i.tree-branch-head'),':after').getPropertyValue('content');";`

Answer (score 1):

Handle pseudo element in selenium webdriver

```
 String script = "return window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('Enter root class name here '),':after').getPropertyValue('content')";
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            String content = (String) js.executeScript(script);
            System.out.println(content);
```

Now use this content string in your assert command or anywhere you want to use , hope this will work for you... Good luck