# How to check input span styled as checkbox is selected using Selenium? Only :: after as the difference between states

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am trying to check whether a checkbox is selected. My checkbox is styled using input and span, **not using the checkbox tag**. As it's not a default checkbox I **can't use** methods such as **isSelected or isChecked** to check its state. I was then trying to check if any class belongs to a state but not the other. However, the only difference I've found so far is that when the element is selected an `::after` appears but not sure how to go about checking this?

I found a tutorial with a similar issue, but don't know much about Javascript and not sure how to adapt it to my case.

https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-locate-After-and-Before-css-tag-in-selenium-webdriver

Before clicked
[image]

After clicked
[image]

That's what is being used and as per @pguardiario answer

```
 System.out.println(js.executeScript("return window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.custom-checkmark'), ':after').getPropertyValue('content')"));
```

But both when it's selected or not it returns the same output (empty string)

**UPDATE**

Found the difference between the selected and unselected states. The `.custom-checkmark:after` style has `display-none` when the checkbox is not selected.
Not sure still how to use this info as that's what I have at moment and they return display none both before and after the checkbox is clicked.

```
@Test
public void testingCheckbox() {

    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) wd;

    System.out.println(js.executeScript("return window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.custom-checkmark'), ':after').getPropertyValue('display')"));

    lp.clickCheckBox();

    System.out.println(js.executeScript("return window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.custom-checkmark'), ':after').getPropertyValue('display')")); 
}
```

[image]

**NEW FINDING**

It seems there's actually 'two checkboxes'. One with the span tag and the other one with the span. They appear together when unselecting some attributes.

[image]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: For Python? Java?

Comment: Can you provide the url web?

Comment: Hi @pguardiario, I'm using Java.

Comment: @Frian, sorry not sure I can provide the url as it's my company's web application and would need approval from them.

Comment: Hi @pguardiario, I've made an update to my post with the difference between the states. Would that help you be able to guide me on locating the element please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the code to work. Targeting the input tag instead of span solved the problem. I had a mistake on my code when tried that first time so that's why though the isSelected field wasn't working and moved on to target the span tag instead which opened this thread here. Sorry about that and thanks for everybody's help.

Comment: Thanks, I went through all the other answers before finally getting to this one...

Answer (score 1):

Try the below CSS selectors for identifying that

```
span.custom-checkmark:after
```

And also please see the below link for more details
[Extracting content in :after using XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40885637/extracting-content-in-after-using-xpath)

Comment: Hi @user3263086, thanks for the reply. I'm afraid I tried it but it didn't work. It gives me an empty string instead when looking for the innerHTML. Tried also with the outer but it made no difference in comparison to when it's not clicked.

Comment: @FrancislainyCampos  Please see my updated answer.it might help you.

Comment: Thanks very much. Sorry, it's actually working already now just can't accept the answer yet.

Answer (score 1):

I can't test it but it should look something like this:

```
driver.executeScript('return window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(".custom-checkmark"), ":after").getPropertyValue("content")')
```

Sorry about the long line btw, Java doesn't have heredocs which makes this painful :(

Comment: Thanks @pguardiario. Unfortunately it didn't work as it returns empty spaces as the content.

Comment: Here I made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0d9tup1k/3/) so you can try it. If there's 2 checkboxes you might need to adjust the css,

Comment: Many thanks for the fiddle. Had never heard of it before but seems interesting. Learned sth new now. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try use `JavascriptExecutor`, import them :

```
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
```

Try this :

```
WebElement chk = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='custom-checkmark' and ./preceding-sibling::*[@id='terms_checkbox']]"));//or you have
String getPro;
getPro = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return window.getComputedStyle(arguments[0], ':after').getPropertyValue('background-color');",chk).toString();
System.out.println(getPro);
chk.click();
Thread.sleep(1000);
getPro = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return window.getComputedStyle(arguments[0], ':after').getPropertyValue('background-color');",chk).toString();
System.out.println(getPro);
```

Not sure with `.getPropertyValue('background-color')`, but this may be a clue.

Comment: Hi @Frian, thanks for the answer. I've updated my question with the JS code I'm using at the moment, targeting the display property instead but not working as it returns none on both cases even when the tick selected is displayed.