# How to get css value of pseudo element with selenium python?

Tags: python, html, css, selenium

I have html o page:

```
<div id="foo" class="bar" title>
  ::before
</div>
```

With Chrome or Firefox on selection `::before` I can see css on Styles tab:

```
.SomeTitle .bar::before{
content: "required_value"
}
```

After selection `<div id="foo" class="bar" title>` it presented in `Pseudo ::before element`. I did try to get value of `content`:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(my_url)
my_element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='foo']")
my_elemet.value_of_css_property("content")
```

But it does returns none. How can I get value of `content`?

Comment: This is not duplicate. I want use python selenium not jquery.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28244911/selenium-webdriver-get-text-from-css-property-content-on-a-before-pseudo-ele

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I did find solution. This is not pure selenium but it does works.

```
browser.execute_script("return window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.SomeTitle .bar'),':before').getPropertyValue('content')")
```

Hope this will helps to someone.