# Click on pseudo ::before or ::after element using Selenium, Python Edition

Tags: python, selenium

This [Java Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45427223/click-on-pseudo-element-using-selenium) of this question is both aptly asked, and answered, at [Java Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45427223/click-on-pseudo-element-using-selenium).

However, the question, and therefore the excellent accepted answer, was specific to ***Java***.

How can this be done with ***Python***? hence asking this question and providing details of my specific case below.

I am trying to click the select all checkbox element *(well, inside the checkbox really)* as shown in the below **picture**:

> [image]

The actual clickable area is sitting inside the checkbox element, represented by the ***::before*** pseudo element in the DOM shown in **picture** above.

Noting that the pseudo elements cannot be referenced using XPATH, I want to access this ::before pseudo element by physically using the mouse click, referencing the ::before element by pointing the mouse to the center of the checkbox at the below XPATH, using ***Selenium Python***:

> //span[text()="Transmission (TX) to eNodeB"]/ancestor::h2/following-sibling::div/descendant::label[1]

The XPATH is working to locate the top left of the checkbox element, validated by the 1 result yellow highlighted using chrome's find element in **picture**.

Comment: Show us your code efforts until now (a minimal reproducible example), and also confirm the url, if it's public facing.

Comment: Isn't the `label` -> `span` text enough to identify the element?

Comment: Unfortunately the url is not public facing. I have not yet written code to achieve the desired result, need to find out how the solution at the referenced Q&A can be adopted to Python, or any other ways to achieve same result. I will share any attempts I will write here.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium no, the //span[@text()='Select all rows'] identifies the //span element, but not the ::before or ::after pseudo elements. However, I have other motivation to use that structure to identify the element, I want to change the "Transmission (TX) to eNodeB" string using a variable to click checkboxes elsewhere in the website DOM.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium no, the //span[@text()='Select all rows'] identifies the //span element, but not the ::before or ::after pseudo elements. However, I have other motivation to use that structure to identify the element, I want to change the "Transmission (TX) to eNodeB" string using a variable to click OTHER "Select all rows" checkboxes elsewhere in the website DOM.

Comment: To change the "Transmission (TX) to eNodeB" string, you don't need to deal with _`::before`_ or _`::after`_, See: [How locate the pseudo-element ::before using Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59706267/7429447)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can select or click CSS pseudo-element since even if you see it in HTML DOM-tree it's **not present in DOM**!

You need to select checkbox input field. Try XPath

```
//input[@type='checkbox']
```

or more specific

```
//div[.//span='Transmission (TX) to eNodeB']//input[@type='checkbox']
```

P.S. To get better solution you need to provide HTML as text for ancestors as well