# How to select pseudo element in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

On web page one control look likes check box but it is not.
I can select element like  `<label class ="control-label">`
It is of size 11X0.

I want to select a control adjacent to above label and in </> element it is :

```
<label class ="control-label"> 
::before
::after
```

I want to select control with ::before having size 22X22.

I tried the way given in
[Click on pseudo element using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45427223/click-on-pseudo-element-using-selenium)
but failed to do so.
I am new to selenium.
Help needed.
Thanks in advance.