# How to get pseudo elements in WebdriverIO+Appium

Tags: appium, pseudo-element, webdriver-io, appium-android, wdio-jasmine

I want to get a value (`content`) from the CSS of a pseudo element (`::before`) while inside a test made using WDIO and Appium for an Android hybrid app because the designer has stored the current responsive-design state there. So my tests would know which layout (elements) to expect.

Multiple answers to related questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28265738/4335271); [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32537863/4335271); [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6338234/4335271)) indicated that using `.getComputedStyle()` might be the only solution. But this does not seem to work in my tests. The error is `window is not defined` for `window.getComputedStyle(...)` or `document is not defined` if I use `document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(...)`. Also selectors themselves can't address pseudo-elements it [seems](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector#Usage_notes).

Example of one of my many attempts:

```
document.defaultView.getComputedStyle($('body'),'::before').getPropertyValue('content')
```

---

**Question**: Do I need to somehow import `window` or `document` to my test? Is there some other way to get `window` or `document` from inside the test?

#### Ultimately: how can I get the `content` value of `::before` of the `<body>` of a hybrid Android app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*Thanks to Jeremy Schneider (@YmerejRedienhcs) & Erwin Heitzman (@erwinheitzman) for help!*</sup>

One solution is to use the [`execute`](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/execute.html) function:

```
let contentMode = browser.execute(() => {
  let style = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('body'),'::before');
  return style.getPropertyValue('content')
});
```

Alternatively *maybe* something could also be done with [`getHTML`](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/element/getHTML.html).